# How to apply specific object style to textFrames, those starting with anchored graphic frame?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I have a document (InDesign CS6) with a story, using text frames as placeholders. These text frames all have a graphic frame as first paragraph, going on with some other paragraphs with text.
Now, i would like to apply an object style to those placeholders.
Please excuse my english :(

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Object" tab of the Find/Replace feature.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to tell, that i have about 6000 of those placeholders. I was looking for a script (javascript or apple script) to handle this.

Comment: The thing is... you didn't provide enough information! Question is: is there anything that distinguishes those objects you want to apply a style to from other text frames in your document? Fill or stroke color? Effects? number of columns, inside margins? etc, etc...

Comment: @utzZ have you looked for a script? have you tried writing a script? Or are you merely hoping someone will write one for you?